# Send new text entry while selenium working asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, webforms, selenium-webdriver

In my asp.net project I am try to send data to selenium web-browser from webform while selenium browser is working. For example, there is a textbox and  button in my webform.When I write text and click button. It starts selenium browser, login page go to messages and send text which i wrote. But when i wanna send another message text in same page, because of postback it starts proggress from begining. In this case i need browser standby , wait me enter another text from my webform and submits it again.Here is my code behind;

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.somesite.com/");
        IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("username"));
        query.SendKeys("blablabla");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys("blablabla");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnLogin")).Submit();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.somesite.com/sendmessage/john");
        new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.LinkText("Message"))));

        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Message")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("MessageText")).SendKeys(txtMessage.Text);


        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
        action.Perform();
    }
```

Thanks, best regards..

Comment: You are running Selenium via a button on an ASP.NET homepage?

Comment: Yes i opened empty asp.net project and page and add simple textbox and button in it.

Comment: Can I ask why? You will end up with a lot of headaches that you find in ASP.NET development when it's unneeded. Stuff like user permissions, IIS settings, postbacks etc. This will just add to your work. You can easily just have this as a console application.

Comment: @Arran well you are absolutely right if i were using jscript post/get cors stuff, but this is why i use selenium, to make those stuff easier but i just need a bit info to use it..

Comment: My point is that by using ASP.NET to drive Selenium you are making this much harder. You will not see your issue if you were to use this as a test library (via NUnit for instance) or a console application.

Comment: @arran i see.. Well can you give me some guide to make it  from console app.

Answer (score 0):

As Arran mentioned in comments, you can use NUnit & NUnit test adapter to run your UI test with VS test explorer or console command. For example your existing code would be like

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestCase123
{
    [Test]
    public void SendMessage()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.somesite.com/");
        IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("username"));
        query.SendKeys("blablabla");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys("blablabla");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnLogin")).Submit();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.somesite.com/sendmessage/john");
        new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.LinkText("Message"))));

        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Message")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("MessageText")).SendKeys(txtMessage.Text);


        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
        action.Perform();
    }
}
```

After you build you can see your test in the test explorer. As per your question, I am afraid you cannot do that. Instead you should use [test case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_case). For example if a test case needs your application to send message twice, you should write your code to send the message twice in a single test not executing the test twice.